# Not looping through entire json array object

Tags: javascript, ajax, loops, xmlhttprequest

I am using XAMPP Apache to do XMLHTTP Javascript (AJAX) request from a json file but I am only looping through two(2) entries instead of the entire array four or five (5). I believe there is a problem with my looping code in both my "next" and "previous" functions. Hitting the next button allow me to go ahead and hitting the previous button allows me to go back but only through two(2

```js
function next(xhttp) {
  var i = 0,
    len;
  //var xhttp;
  //xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var users = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
  len = users.length;
  if (i < len - 1) {
    i++;
  }
  var usersText = '';
  usersText +=
    '<div class="next">' +
    'ID: ' + users[i].id + '<br>' +
    'Name: ' + users[i].name + '<br>' +
    'Email: ' + users[i].email;

  document.getElementById("usersNav").innerHTML = usersText;
}

function previous(xhttp) {
  var i = 0,
    len;
  //var xhttp;
  //xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var users = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
  len = users.length
  if (i > 0) {
    i--;
  }

  var usersText2 = '';
  usersText2 +=
    '<div class="prev">' +
    'ID: ' + users[i].id[navigation image][1] + '<br>' +
    'Name: ' + users[i].name + '<br>' +
    'Email: ' + users[i].email;

  document.getElementById("usersNav").innerHTML = usersText2;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc('users.json',previous)"><<</button>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc('users.json',next)">>></button>
```

I am only getting two entries to toggle through....if I click next and previous. I should be getting all the entries which is about 4-5.

Comment: `i` needs to be a global variable so it keeps its value between calls to the functions.

Comment: You snippet doesn't work. loadDoc is not defined.

Comment: @shadoe2020 Here is the loadDoc function. It works when loading the json api as a table, individual user and multiple users....function loadDoc(url,cFunction){
  var xhttp;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
      cFunction(this);
      //If we want to get the response Header
      //document.getElementById("responseHeader").innerHTML = this.getAllResponseHeaders();
    }
  };
xhttp.open ("GET",url,true);
xhttp.send();

Comment: @Barmar......you are correct. I needed to make it a global function by moving the declaration outside of the next and previous functions.  Thank you. It works now.